# How to get size maximized without set to maximized?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmainwindow

Worked on Win10 with QT5.

`showMaximized` can make the window maximized. However, if double click the title bar, it will resize. So I want to set the window as big as possible (not fullscreen, still want Windows task bar), and set it fixed, which makes double click disabled. How should I get the size max possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can determine the size of the current screen

```
int  screen_height = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().height();
int  screen_width = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width();
```

you can do something like this

```
Widget* w = new Widget;
int  screen_height = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().height();
int  screen_width = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width();
w->setMinimumSize(screen_width-10, screen_height-screen_height/12);
w->showMaximized();
```

Comment: This way will get screen size, which count in task bar size.

Comment: How should I get the size max possible? this is your max possible size ,)) and as for not closing the Windows taskbar, this is manual work, the taskbar may be set vertically, either from the top or horizontally, or it may not be there

Comment: Agree. But the behaviour of maximize and full screen is different.